# scaling the size of background image in list navigation menu

Tags: html, css, background-image, fluid-layout

I wish to build a sprite navigation menu using an unorderd list with a background image.  I want this menu to expand to fit the browser window.  In my code   `<img src="images/css-sprite-example.png" alt="header" />`scales the image to fit the full width of the screen.

How would I go about it to have that same image used in the menu and the menu expand to fill the width of the screen.

I am using the CSS `#menu li a{background:url('images/css-sprite-example.png') no-repeat; width:100%; height 100%; display:block;}` but the 100% only scales the image to the actual size of the image.

Obviously I will have to change how my CSS selectors will have to be in percent not pixels.

Many thanks

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#menucontainer {
    background: blue;
    text-align: center;
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
}
#menucontainer img {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
#menucontainer ul {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 1px solid pink;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    list-style:none;
}
#menucontainerr li {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
ul#menu{margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;}
#menu li{overflow:hidden; text-indent:-9999px; display:inline; float:left; margin-right:1px;}
#menu li a{background:url('images/css-sprite-example.png') no-repeat; width:100%; height 100%; display:block;}
    /* Home Button */
    #menu li.home{width:215px; height:52px;}
    #menu li.home a{background-position:-5px -5px;}
    #menu li.home a:hover{background-position:-5px -15px;}
    #menu li.home a.selected{background-position:-5px -25px;}
    /* About Button */
    #menu li.about{width:120px; height:52px;}
    #menu li.about a{background-position:-125px -5px;}
    #menu li.about a:hover{background-position:-125px -15px;}
    #menu li.about a.selected{background-position:-125px -25px;}
    #menu li.about a.selected:hover{background-position:-125px -35px;}
    /* Contact Button */
    #menu li.contact{width:80px; height:52px;}
    #menu li.contact a{background-position:-250px -5px;}
    #menu li.contact a:hover{background-position:-10% -15px;}
    #menu li.contact a.selected{background-position:-250px -25px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="menucontainer">
        <img src="images/css-sprite-example.png" alt="header" />
        <ul id="menu">  
            <li class="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>  
            <li class="about"><a class="selected" href="#">About</a></li>  
            <li class="contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>  
        </ul>  
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scale a background image you need to use `background-size`, see http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/properties/background-size and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size

Comment: Thank you for the details and the prompt reply., I have just tried several of the settings but to no avail.  In fact I tried: `#menu li a{background:url('images/css-sprite-example.png') no-repeat; background-size:8px 6px; display:block;}` I would expect this to shrink the image down to a tiny size to demonstrate that it works.  However there is no change in the size.  Clearly all is not well with my code.  Have you any other suggestions? Many thanks

Comment: I can't really say without seeing the page. Do you still have an image element inside the anchor? That would obscure the background, which might explain why the size isn't changing. Also, try looking at the anchor in your browser's document inspector to check its size and see if it has the correct css attributes applied to it.

Comment: Thanks Daniel.  I will try some experiments, unfortunately for me I do not know what you mean in your last comment (Do you still have an image element inside the anchor & document inspector to check its size and see if it has the correct css attributes).  Thanks again